# access in a component a variable that is declared in the template

Tags: angular, modal-dialog, ng-bootstrap

I am using bg boostrap modal.

I have a button that that has access to the `content` object that is defined only in the view

```
<button (click)="open(content)">Launch demo modal</button>
```

the `open` method is defined in the component, but the `content` object only exists in the template.

How can I call `this.open(accessContentHere)` from inside my component ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the ViewChild decorator for this. In your component, import `ViewChild`, then set the name of the `template local variable` as the parameter:

```
import {..., Component, OnInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core'

...

export class YourComponent extends Component implements OnInit {
    @ViewChild('content') content;

    ngOnInit() {
        this.open(content);
    }

    open(myContent) { //...}

    ...

}
```